# Can Popup page use DOM elements created in Background Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Actually, I want to store some data in background page and the popup page just show that part of data say Data as a div element created in background page document.createElement("div"). Here, the background page will register some listeners to the tab update and change the Data elements accordingly. What the popup will  do is to get that Data and appendit use the document.appendChild(Data).

(The purpose I intend is this will cause the popup changes immediately while the tab updage is triggered.)

However, the elements are shown as usual, what I am facing very headache is I have registered the onclick for the div object in backgroundpage as onclick="chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().somefunc()". However, the first time, all the click will triger the right behavior but after the popup loses foucs and get focus again, all the click won't work.

I try to put something like change the  onclick="somefunc()" and leave the func within the script of popup page. And there I want to log whether it is called by console.log("clicked"). Here, something unbelievable happens, the function is succefully trigerred BUT the console is null here, I cannot even call chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() as well.

Here are a list of questions, maybe very hard to express for me...
1. Whether I can reuse the DOM element from the background page to the popup page directly by appendChild(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getElementById()?
2.Will the onclick event registered in the background page still work in the popup pages?
3. What's the problem with the problem I am encountering? I have tried many ways to find out the reason but all in vain at last...

Best Regards,

If you need any more information, please let  me know.

(PS: I am wonderning if it is called something like the event propogation, however, I am not an expert in this two pages communicating...)